# zsh completion for ssh confuses hostnames with local files

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

suppose I have following entry in my `/etc/hosts`

```
192.168.1.10      server1.mydomain.com
```

and I have a directory `SERVER-FILES` in current dir. I want to `scp` the directory `SERVER-FILES` somewhere. I type `SE` and use autocompletion to complete the directory name:

```
$ scp -rp SE<TAB>
```

This completion should be totally unambiguous. But zsh autocomplletion tries to be too smart, and treats hostnames case-insensitive, and thus attempts to match `SE` to hostnames:

```
$ scp -rp SE<TAB>
SERVER-FILES/
server1.mydomain.com
```

How can I disable this annoying feature, where zsh is trying to match hostnames case-insensitive, and therefore completes `SE<TAB> to` server1.mydomain.com` ?

## UPDATE:

Based on suggestions from `@zeppelin`, I have changed the following line in the ssh completion file `Unix/_ssh`:

```
- compadd -M 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|.=* r:|=*' "$@" $config_hosts
+ compadd "$@" $config_hosts
```

but that did not help. It has absolutely no effect.

And I don't understand the answer from `@Tomasz Pala`. My zsh completion is not case-insensitive.

Please sopmebody just tell me what I need to change in `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_foo` to change this behaviour.

## UPDATE 2

I have finally narrowed the problem down, and found out why the solution from `@Tomasz Pala` did work for him, but not for me:

When I change the `Unix/_hosts` file on a newly setup machine/user account, the solution works.

```
scp -r SE<TAB>
```

The above command ignores `server1.mydomain.com` in `/etc/hosts`, and only offers local directory `SERVER-FILES` for completion.

But this does not work for me on my existing user account, because I have
`server.mydomain.com` in my `~/.ssh/config`. When I remove the entry, then everything works as desired.

But how can I make this hack work even with my current `~/.ssh/config` ?

Comment: does this work for you? `zstyle ':completion::complete:scp:*' hosts off`

Comment: `scp` could complete either a filename or a hostname at that position, so matches both the directory and the hostname.

Comment: I am not trying to disable hostname completion. I just want to disable the nonsense feature of case insensitive hostname completion.

Comment: I think that you would have to write your own matcher for that. As said before, at this argument position both hosts and files are possible and zsh proposition seems correct. You could start typing your argument with `./SE` to tell zsh that you mean a file.

Comment: @Kalavan - yes, at this argument position both hosts and files are possible. But there is no host matching `SE`. I want completion for both hostname and files, but I don't want to match hostnames case-insensitive.

Comment: @400theCat I cannot reproduce this with a clean Zsh install plus `autoload -Uz compinit && compinit`. Either you are not using `compinit` to do completion or then there's something in your config that's messing things up.

Comment: @400theCat Perhaps you could share in your answer what options and `zstyle` settings you have set? That would make it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @400theCat Also, are you using any kind of framework, such as OhMyZsh, Prezto or Zimfw? A bit more info about your setup would really be helpful, as it's otherwise impossible to figure what's going on here. Because this is not the default behavior.

Comment: @Marlon Richert - I have pasted the relevant parts of my `.zshrc`. Please see my `UPDATE 2`. I am not using any framework, just plain `.zshrc`. The `.zshrc` now contains the added rules for `ssh` and `scp`. Currently, when I type  `scp S<TAB>` it completes `server` from my hosts file. Same for `ssh S<TAB>` where it also completes `server`. I would like to change that, so that `scp -rp S<TAB>` only completes local file matching `S*`, or if no such file exists, does not complete anything.

Comment: @400theCat Thanks, I'm able to reproduce it now.

Comment: @MartinVegter I’m not sure what you want for your bounty. Can you explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second answer tries to explain that you need to do two things:

1_ make sure your general matching rules are not case-insensitive (`matcher-list`) - from the updated question it's not,

2_ change *Unix/(Type/)_hosts* (the actual location might vary, but **not** the *Unix/_ssh* - this one handles `~/.ssh/config` hosts, see below) last 2 lines to:

```
_wanted hosts expl host \
   compadd -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z} r:|.=* r:|=*' -a "$@" - _hosts
```

All of this was already summarized in my answer, so simply try doing this without reading all the rationale before. Also, since your global config is not case-insensitive, the @zeppelin's answer should also work, although it doesn't use $fpath and removes also small->CAPS matching of the hosts.

I did test this with your settings from the update and it works as expected.

Update: remember that `zsh` keeps it's functions loaded, so after modifying the `_hosts` you need to reload it either by logging in fresh, or:

```
unfunction _hosts
autoload -Uz _hosts
```

Also remember that `zsh` can have the scripts 'compiled' in `zwc` form (`zcompile [file]`) and if such file exists and is newer than the source it would be used instead.

Ad. update 2:

Handling the `~/.ssh/config` defined hosts is actually pretty much the same as for `_hosts` - depending on your [zsh version](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/4977ec13982bc851668e85924e30a57c4e304b6e) in either [Unix/(Command/)_ssh](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/47430bcd7cb2fade4d8753d920a2720eeca52f6a/Completion/Unix/Command/_ssh#L687) or [Unix/(Type/)_ssh_hosts](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Completion/Unix/Type/_ssh_hosts#L51) change the

`compadd -M 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|.=* r:|=*' "$@" $config_hosts`

line to

`compadd -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z} r:|.=* r:|=*' "$@" $config_hosts`

Comment: thank you, but this does not work as I wanted: 1) `touch SSS.TXT` ; `scp -rp S<TAB>` still offers completion for `server.domain.org` from /etc/hosts. It should only offer completion of local file `S*`, if it exists. 2) `ssh S<TAB>` also offers completion `server.domain.org`. It should offer nothing, because I have `server.domain.org` in my /etc/hosts, and not `SERVER.DOMAIN.ORG`

Comment: If so then either you don't use the modified `_hosts` file (I've updated my answer), or you're stuck in 1st point of that answer. To verify the former problem - simply put some bogus code or `echo` in the `_hosts` and see if this is the code that is actually being used (you might have some other directory included in $fpath which holds previous `_hosts`). As for the 1st problem: `zstyle | grep -A1 matcher-list`

Comment: I have found out why your solution did not work fore me. Please see my `UPDATE 2` for details.

Comment: I'm glad you've narrowed this down to local config - I've just posted updated response which handles also these hosts.

Comment: everything works perfectly now. Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are editing a wrong line.

AFAIK *config_hosts* in *Unix/_ssh* refers to the host entries in your *~./ssh/config*, not */etc/hosts*.

The completion rules for */etc/hosts* are defined a bit earlier, in the following block:

```
# If users-hosts matches, we shouldn't complete anything else.
if [[ "$IPREFIX" == *@ ]]; then
  _combination -s '[:@]' my-accounts users-hosts "users=${IPREFIX/@}" hosts "$@" && return
else
  _combination -s '[:@]' my-accounts users-hosts \
    ${opt_args[-l]:+"users=${opt_args[-l]:q}"} hosts "$@" && return
fi
```

but this in turn just reuses the *hosts* style defined in *Unix/_hosts*

So if you edit the *compadd* definition at the end of the *Unix/_hosts* file like this:

```
#_wanted hosts expl host \
#    compadd -M 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z} r:|.=* r:|=*' -a "$@" - _hosts
_wanted hosts expl host \
     compadd -a "$@" - _hosts
```

you should get the behavior you want.

P.S.

Please note that editing a system-wide completion files is not generally a very good practice, so you may want to just redefine *hosts* in your local ZSH config instead, e.g. by adding a function like that to your ~./zsh:

```
_hosts() { compadd $(getent hosts | tr -s ' ' '\t' | cut -f2) }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two aspects of this question.

1. the global zsh completion with case-insensitiveness. It's very popular, but IMHO pointless, to do it two-way. Since I don't type in caps usually (or by mistake), let's treat all the CAPS as intentional:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}'`

```
mkdir DOC drone
ls D[tab] => DOC
ls d[tab] => drone DOC
ls Dr[tab] => [empty]
```

The problem with matcher-list is that this [is called very early and cannot be replaced on per-command/argument basis](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2020/msg00067.html).

And since matcher-list repeated values are being concatenated (quote from the documentation: "*This option may be given more than once. In this case all match-specs given are concatenated with spaces between them to form the specification string to use*"), you cannot override this later, e.g.

`compdef '_hosts -M m:' foo`

won't revoke the previous definition from _hosts file. So if you have `{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}` in your global configuration, you won't be able to clear this, even with `matcher`, e.g.:

`zstyle ':completion:*:scp:*:*' matcher "m:{A-Z}={A-Z}"`

won't help. Sorry, you need to start resolving this issue at global level. The trade-off solution could be to have two-pass global:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{A-Z}={a-z}'`

```
ls d[tab] => DOC drone
ls D[tab] => DOC
ls Dr[tab] => drone
```

2. Second part of the problem is function-defined matcher-list. As stated above, this is not clearable, so you need to cope with this like already covered in @zeppelin answer, by changing zsh-provided file:

_hosts:

```
[....]
_wanted hosts expl host \
    compadd -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z} r:|.=* r:|=*' -a "$@" - _hosts
```

Now, and with system-wide matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}':

```
scp d[tab] => /directory/ DOC drone /remote host name/ docker /user/ daemon
scp D[tab] => DOC
```

The proposed solution with altering original completion files is not the right way to do, just like @zeppelin noted ...but creating own host-fetching function is also flawned. Proper solution is unfortunately up to zsh developers, who might either add a matcher-clearing option, define some new style or simply fix the completion function to not ignore case on it's own, just follow the global settings.

Yet even with this issue there is nice and clean solution - instead of modifying (probably some distro package provided) /usr/share/zsh/... one can put the fixed copy in /etc/zsh/functions and simply tell zsh to use this location: `fpath=(/etc/zsh/functions $fpath)`. This way you avoid overwriting the file after system update.

### Summarizing

1. change your global matcher-list:

`zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{A-Z}={a-z}'`

2. put modified _hosts file in some /etc/zsh or $HOME location:

`fpath=(/etc/zsh/functions $fpath)`

/etc/zsh/functions/_hosts:

```
[....]
_wanted hosts expl host \
    compadd -M 'm:{a-z}={A-Z} r:|.=* r:|=*' -a "$@" - _hosts
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to change any completion functions to get what you want. Just add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
# $PREFIX is the part of the current word that's to the left of the cursor.
# $SUFFIX is the part of the current word that's to the right of the cursor.
# Let's ignore all host completions that don't explicitly match what we've typed, 
# but allow for additional characters at the cursor position and at the end of what 
# we've typed. This makes the matching case sensitive.
# `(b)` escapes characters that are significant to globbing.
zstyle -e ':completion:*:hosts' ignored-patterns 'reply=(
  "^(${(b)PREFIX}*${(b)SUFFIX}*)"
)'

# But if that would lead to no results, then offer the ignored completions anyway.
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored
```

I've tested this with the config and test cases you posted and it works.

Documentation:

- [completion context](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Completion-System-Configuration)
- [`ignored-patterns`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-ignored_002dpatterns_002c-completion-style)
- [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-parameter-expansion-flags)
- [globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)
- [`ignored` completer](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fignored)

Comment: @400theCat Have you tried this yet?

Comment: can you please explain what these two lines do? Looks quite convoluted, and looks like this is not specific to scp/ssh.

Comment: @400theCat I added more explanation and made the code specific to scp/ssh.

Comment: This is not a solution to the given problem - this changes entire completion for the command, including local files: `touch abc; scp *bc[tab]` won't get expanded to `abc`. And obviously won't work for other commands using _hosts completion.

Comment: @TomaszPala @400theCat I updated my answer to apply to _all_ completions that generate `hosts` (and only those that generates `hosts`). Happy now? 

Comment: Definitely:) now it targets the problem itself and is in fact a clever solution - instead of altering the set that is generated, filter out what's not expected, and only after that fallback into "magic" completions (like `scp *host_pattern`). Too bad OP is so inactive here, this answer deserves second half of the bounty...